# Why Is My Media Card Reader not working in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sd-card, card-reader

I have a Dell 2407FWP monitor that has a built in media card reader and USB ports.

The USB Ports work fine but the media card reader shows up in Devices as a USB 2.0 device with the error that it can't start. The card reader worked fine under XP Pro SP3 so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please see http://superuser.com/questions/64417/windows-7-does-not-recognize-media-card-reader-after-upgrade-from-vista for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your drivers aren't supported, since it is being recognized which would indicate it's probably not a hardware problem.

Comment: I'm seeing more people asking this question while searching for drivers, so it's probably a known/unsolved issue

Comment: @studiohack - Since there doesn't seem to be any way to send you a message in private and I can only post here, would you please explain to me why you edited MY post to remove my closing - "Thanks, Val"? Is there some policy I am unaware of that prevents users from displaying common courtesy and expressing their appreciation for the help of other users?

Comment: Mostly yes @Valek, we discourage any content within the questions that aren't really related to the question. Why? Well because after your problem is solved, it will be viewed by lot's of other users for whom this has no value. So we try to keep it clean, if you want to show appreciation: upvote, upvote a lot!

Comment: "Thank You" HAS NO VALUE??? and "We try to keep it clean"?? You make it sound as if I were telling some to FU$K Off or something...That just blows my mind that common courtesy is frowned upon, edited out even, but oh well, if that's the way you like it then so be it.

Comment: @Valek, we have upvotes, bounties and accepting answers to show gratitude. You would be surprised by the volume of questions getting answers that only contain: "Thank you!" So yes, they are discouraged. That's not to say we don't want you to care @Valek