# Windows 7 does not recognize Media Card Reader after upgrade from Vista

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, compatibility, card-reader

*This question is a result of the issue stated in [this SU-question](https://superuser.com/questions/63962/ide-controller-compatibility-problem-during-win7-x64-upgrade). Please read it beforehand.*

I have upgraded my OS from Windows Vista Home Premium x64 to Windows 7 Home Premium x64. It's a legal upgrade. Upgrade was successful except one problem: Windows 7 does not recognize the Media Card Reader of my desktop PC anymore. When I open the Device Manager, nothing seems wrong. Before the upgrade, K, L, M, etc. drives were active as Media Card Reader drives. Now they are not present.

Is there any way to make Win7 recognize this device? Or do I have to make a clean install as a desperate remedy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have performed the following steps and now the problem is solved!

**1)** Disconnected Media Card Reader and reconnected it. I wanted Windows to automatically detect the hardware change. Details of the first step:

a) Turned off Windows.
b) Disconnected Media Card Reader.
c) Turned on Windows.
d) Turned off Windows.
e) Connected Media Card Reader.
f) Turned on Windows.

**2)** Disabled and re-enabled the controllers.

a) Opened Device Manager.
b) Expanded IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers.
c) Uninstalled each item one by one.
d) Restarted the computer.

**3)** After the computer started, Windows reinstalled all the controllers that I've uninstalled. I've inserted a SD Card to the Media Card Reader to see whether it was working. And voila! It was working.

The only difference with Vista is: I cannot see the drive letters in `My Computer` unless I insert a media into the reader. In Vista, I was able to see the drives even when there is no media in them. Maybe this is handled differently in Windows 7, or related to some adjustments, but it's even better for me.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 did not recognize my media card reader either. I had to install the drivers for it and then I was able to use it.

I should add that this was on the Beta and RC versions of Windows 7 x64. I haven't had a chance to install my legal retail copy yet ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, rodey. Unfortunately, I don't know the type of my media card reader. It's not written on the device either. Where can I find the driver?

Comment: Check the support page from the manufacturer of your computer. They should have all the drivers you need.