# Get a driver for SD/MMC card

Tags: windows-7, mmc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 does not recognize Media Card Reader after upgrade from Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/64417/windows-7-does-not-recognize-media-card-reader-after-upgrade-from-vista)

Hi, I updated to Windows 7 and everything works fine except for my SD/MMC card.  Windows can not recognize it anymore.  I try to update the driver, but it can not find any.  Does anyone have a solution besides get a USB reader?

Comment: Model number would be helpful. Did you go to the manufacturer's site to look for drivers?